# Div won't position itself at the bottom of parent div

Tags: css

This should be fairly simple but for some reason I can't get my "footer" div to be placed at the bottom of the "container" div. This pertains to the master page format so if I adjust it to look good on one page it won't on another. Can someone take a quick look and help me out?

```
#container {
background-color: #fafafa;
height: auto;
width: 1112px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#footer {
background-color: #fafafa;
width: 1112px;
height: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

#ftr-nav {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
float: right;
padding: 15px 30px 0 0;
}

.ftr-link-home {
font: 9px #0094ff;
}

.ftr-link-admin {
font: 9px #0094ff;
}

#copy {
float: right;
padding: 0 15px 0 0;
font-size: small;
position: absolute;
right: 115px;
bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Develop_er/c32Mm/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
html,body
{
   height: 100%;
}
#container {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 100%; /* <--- */
    width: 1112px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c32Mm/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Adding height to the #container places everything right.